# Eliminar un dato en arreglos de estructuras

Tags: c#, estructuras-de-datos

Estoy estudiando ingeniería en sistemas computacionales, y tengo una práctica en donde uso arreglos de estructuras, y tengo que crear un método que elimine el dato guardado en un array (este array es definido por el usuario). Ya tengo la mayor parte del código, en total son tres métodos, buscar e insertar datos. Esos métodos ya los tengo, sólo me falta el método eliminar.

Anexo el código para que me ayuden, gracias.

public class Cliente

```
{
    //Arreglo de estructura
    TipoPersona[] Personas;
    public int N;
    string Buscar;

    public void Eliminar_Cliente()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Nombre del cliente a buscar: ");
        Buscar = Console.ReadLine();
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            if (Personas[i].Nombre == Buscar)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Elemento encontrado");
            }

            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Elemento no encontrado");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: para que ese ejercicio tenga sentido como estructura de datos, deberías de manejar la sentencia struct y el suso de punteros. saludos

Answer (score 0):

Esta opción elimina el dato pero cambia la longitud del arreglo:

```
if (Personas[i].Nombre == Buscar){
                Console.WriteLine("Elemento encontrado");
                Personas = Personas.Where( p => p != Personas[i]).ToArray();
                break;
         }
```

Esta elimina el dato pero mantiene el arreglo del mismo tamaño:

```
if (Personas[i].Nombre == Buscar){
                    Console.WriteLine("Elemento encontrado");
                    Personas[i] = null;
                    break;
             }
```

Answer (score 0):

Si solo puede usar las clases de array entonces podria ayudar

[Array.FindAll(T[], Predicate) Method](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.findall?view=netframework-4.8)

entonces buscas las coincidencias

```
private string nombre = "";

public bool BuscarPersonaPorNombre(TipoPersona p)
{
    return p.Nombre != nombre;
}

public void Eliminar_Cliente()
{

    Console.WriteLine("Nombre del cliente a buscar: ");
    nombre = Console.ReadLine();

    Personas = Array.FindAll(Personas, BuscarPersonaPorNombre).ToArray();
}
```

En este caso como quieres usar el `Array.FindAll()` para eliminar se debe buscar los que no coincidan con el nombre, asi los coincidentes no los retorna como parte del nuevo array que asigne

Si lo quieres hacer con `linq` es mas simple

```
public void Eliminar_Cliente()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Nombre del cliente a buscar: ");
    string nombre = Console.ReadLine();

    Personas = Personas.Where(p=> p.Nombre != nombre).ToArray();
}
```

es mas simple porque el predicado se define como lambda

[Expresiones lambda (Guía de programación de C#)](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/lambda-expressions)

[Language-Integrated Query (LINQ)](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/linq/)

Bueno en realidad usando el FindAll() tambien se puede usar una predicate con lambda, si es que te animas a aplicarlo seria

```
public void Eliminar_Cliente()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Nombre del cliente a buscar: ");
    string nombre = Console.ReadLine();

    Personas = Array.FindAll(Personas, p=> p.Nombre != nombre).ToArray();
}
```